# Can't believe I have to ask this, but how do I get the route params from the get request in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

So I sit on the route defined as `/article/:id` on the client, and I query the server API like this:

```
const res = await axios.get(url + '/api/article')
```

(Don't worry about `url`, it's just to get the absolute path.)

Then I have my route:

```
router.get('/article', function(req, res) {
  //I want to find the id from the params
  //Trying fucking everything
  console.log("host", req.get('host')) // 'localhost:3000'
  console.log("url", req.url) // '/article'
  console.log("query", req.query) // '{}'
 })
```

Apparently this is crazy stuff in the Express/axios world, because I've spent the entire day trying to find out how to do this, but there is NO information out there on this subject.

How do I accomplish this stupidly simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is

```
const res = await axios.get(url + '/api/article')
```

You do not send an id. If you want to give a query you should

```
const res = await axios.get(url + '/api/article?id=theId')
```

and use `req.query.id`
or you have to change the route to

```
router.get('/article/:id', ....
```

call `const res = await axios.get(url + '/api/article/theId')`

and use `req.params.id`

Answer (score -1):

```
router.get('/article/:id', function(req, res) {
    //I want to find the id from the params
    console.log(req.params.id)
})
```

Taken from here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html